# Can I hook when user copy or paste on TextView?

Tags: android

When user copy or paste on TextView,
Is there anyone explains me what happen on TextView.
If some methods called while user click 'Copy' or 'Paste' in menus,
I'd like to hook them and replace them with my own one.

Here is what I want to do.
1. user copy or paste some string to my TextView.
2. some string copied and paste on my Textview.
3. Before some string is added on Textview, I want to check or change string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to do this with the [`onTextContextMenuItem()` method](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#onTextContextMenuItem(int)) checking for [`copy`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.id.html#copy) or [`paste`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.id.html#paste).

Alternatively you can use a [`TextWatcher`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextWatcher.html) to monitor changes in a `TextView` but this doesn't differentiate between typing and cutting and pasting.  Add a `TextWatcher` with the [`addTextChangedListener()` method](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#addTextChangedListener(android.text.TextWatcher)).